# Xcode constraints identifiers not reflected in Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xcode to create the layouts of my Xamarin iOS app.

The problem is that the identifiers I add to the constraints in Xcode are not reflected in Visual Studio.

[image]

Is there something specific I need to do in order for them to be reflected in Visual Studio? Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: If you copy the Storyboard or xib file to Visual Studio. The identifier can be gotten: `var constraintIdentifier = MyConstraint.GetIdentifier()`;

Comment: Do you mean that after every change I do in Interface builder I will need to manually copy the XML?

Comment: I did't find the identifier on Visual Studio. So if you really want this feature. You can copy the total file to VS.

Comment: I tried using constraint "Identifier" for layout debugging purposes as shown in your illustration. `myConstraint.GetIdentifier()` returns null in VS. Another observation: safe area layout guides IDs assigned by the system do show up, the ones that you set in IB do not.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't get an answer to the question, I wanted to share what I did eventually. This is not a solution, but some kind of workaround.

The best solution I could find was creating the identifiers in VS instead of Interface Builder. I've created the layouts in Interface Builder, but added the identifiers of the constraints in VS.

I highly suggest not to open the Storyboard in both VS and Interface Builder simultaneously, as it caused me quite a few problems. Save your changes in one and just then open the other.

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: How did you assign `Identifier` in Visual Studio? I do the same thing you do: Create storyboard layouts in IB and then create outlets in VS. Constraint outlet corresponds to `Name` in VS. Where's `Identifier`? I can confirm that VS messes up storyboard constraints. This happens even if you have Xcode closed. With Xcode  and VS fighting over a storyboard (open in both) things get really bad. I wish VS did not have a poor copy of IB at all. Stripped down tooling for JUST OUTLETS would be perfect. I have lost days of work because of VS `IOS Designer` overwriting the storyboard.

Comment: visual studio on macbook combined with any use of xib files is trash, I've found 20 bugs in 10 minutes useing it, such a crap tool, and unfortunately there's no way out, if you need to develop for xamarin..

Comment: If you're facing the issue in my original question, please note that you can create outlets for constraints from Xcode Interface Builder.